# Are location permissions somehow auto included in Adobe AIR for iOS?

Tags: ios, air, adobe, plist, cllocation

In my application I include a 3rd party SDK which has the capability of asking for background location permissions. However I do not want this feature or the permissions popup in my app. From what I can tell this should be as simple as not including the NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription in my plist.

As per Apple's documentation on NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription:

> This key is required when you use the requestAlwaysAuthorization method of the CLLocationManager class to request authorization for location services. If this key is not present and you call the requestAlwaysAuthorization method, the system ignores your request and prevents your app from using location services. 
>   https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CocoaKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009251-SW18

However the app clearly is capable of calling for permissions as the popup still shows when utilizing the SDK. When using the SDK in a non-AIR test app I do not have this issue.

Ideally I am looking to prevent these popups as this SDK is integral to the product. How can I tell AIR not to include this capability?

Answer (score 0):

No, location permissions are not auto included with the AIR SDK.

The NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription key is a requirement, it is not the element that initiates the location permission.

This is also a new requirement, so for older iOS versions this does not apply.

It sounds like your third party SDK is the issue, perhaps contact the developers and enquire with them.